# App with BundleID not found in Provisioning Portal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

I have an app "TestApp" with BundleID: ABCD12234.com.mycompany.testapp on itunesconnect.
In my Provisioning Portal there is no App that has AppID: ABCD12234.com.mycompany.testapp but I have an app with AppID: EFGH5678.com.mycompany.testapp
So is has the same Bundle Identifier but different Bundle Seed ID.

I now want to push an update to the TestApp on itunesconnect.
How can I do that?
Or can I even to that?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you release the first version of the app? You had to use that App ID to generate a distribution profile and then upload the app. Also how did the bundle prefix change? From my understanding the bundle prefix (ABCD12234) should be your Team ID and should not change.

Comment: The app was released by the company I work for before I came on board. When I came on board, there was no App with that prefix.

Comment: Could you ask them which App ID they used to generate the distribution profile? Is there a wildcard App ID they used (`com.company.*`)? If the exact same App ID isn't selected in iTunes Connect, then I don't think it was used to submit the app. I could be wrong though (again still not sure how the prefix could have changed, should be Team ID for company).

Comment: The developers that worked on it are long gone and no one else knows anything about this issue. I think I will have to reach out to apple.